# Nested directive parameter in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker, directive

i'm working with Freemarker in a Java project. 
I've defined a custom directive, as @mycustomdirective

Does this custom directive support other directive as parameter?

i.e :

> <@mycustomdirective parameter="<@othercustomdirective parameter2="..." />" />

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported; you can only call `#function`-s and methods inside an expression (be it a parameter value or something else).

This actually has a reason: Directives meant to output markup, and functions/methods are assumed to generate plain text (or numbers, booleans, etc). Thus when you insert an expression with `${exp}`, it's subject to auto-escaping (via `#escape` ATM... so it's "semi-automatic"), while a directive call isn't, so the distinction is important. Parameter values are expressions, so, they meant to be non-markup, and of course, while it's possible to insert non-markup into markup (via escaping), the opposite is fundamentally impossible.

But if you really want to pass around directive-output in expressions, there's hack:

```
<#assign captured><@myotherdirective /></#assign>
<@mydirective parameter=captured />
```